# Kinto postgresql connection not released

Tags: postgresql, heroku, kinto

I deployed kinto on heroku using this base https://github.com/Kinto/kinto-heroku 
My app using kinto is working.
Then I added some monitoring using the `__heartbeat__` endpoint.
After a few minutes all the (20) connection of my heroku postgresql (free) instance where taken.
I've tried the `pool_size` setting but when all the pool connections where taken kinto is again unable to work it out (pool timeout errors).
It seams that kinto is not releasing the connexions created with the heartbeat endpoint...

Can you give me some suggestion ?

Comment: https://github.com/Kinto/kinto/issues/819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have been fixed in Kinto 4.2.0 thank you for reporting it: https://github.com/Kinto/kinto/releases/tag/4.2.0